# Getting an array of dates (yearly and absolute)

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have the following 2 functions + 1 in progress:

```
    public static IEnumerable<LockedDate> GetAllByEmployee(int employeeID)
    {
        var v = LockedDates.GetAll();
        return from p in v where p.EmployeeID == employeeID select p;
    }

    public static IEnumerable<LockedDate> GetAllByCompany()
    {
        var v = LockedDates.GetAll();
        return from p in v where p.EmployeeID == null select p;
    }

    public static List<LockedDate> GetAllForEmployee(int employeeID)
    {
        var empList = GetAllByEmployee(employeeID);
        var compList = GetAllByCompany();
        //What do???
        return from p in empList and from q in compList where p and q are not duplicate . toList()
    }
```

These use LINQ-SQL.

A LockedDate has a Date and an IsYearly bool. If IsYearly is true then the year should not be considered. Time should never be considered.

I now need a function that will include all the LockedDates that the employee has and the company ones into one list, without any duplicates. So if IsYearly && dd/mm are == or !IsYearly && dd/mm/yyyy are == then there is a duplicate. What might be an efficient, non-naive way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What this condition means `if IsYearly && dd/mm are == or !IsYearly && dd/mm/yyyy are ==`? Equal to what?

Comment: Equal to one that is already in the list, first I would add all the employee dates, then only the company dates that are not duplicates. Above I defined what a duplicate is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var yearly = source.Where(p => p.IsYearly)
                   .GroupBy(p => new { Month = p.Date.Month, Day = p.Date.Day })
                   .Select(g => g.First());
var nonYearly = source.Where(p => !p.IsYearly)
                      .GroupBy(p => p.Date.Date)
                      .Select(g => g.First());

return yearly.Union(nonYearly).ToList();
```

`source` could be done easily by `Union` method:

```
var source = GetAllByEmployee(employeeID).Union(GetAllByCompany());
```

Comment: Will this consider the case where 2 yearly dates have the same month and day?

Comment: Yes, they would be treated as equal.

Comment: What would I have to do if I want to do something similar, but this time with a date range. Say I have Jan 22 2013 to Feb 12 2014 inclusive. But this time the list would be of Date and any IsYearly would include the years in the range, so Id have dec 25 2013 and dec 25 2014 too.

Comment: I don't really understand this. Maybe you should post another question about that... With sample data, etc.

Comment: See my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15412325/get-a-list-of-dates-in-a-date-range

Answer (score 0):

cant you do this

```
    var v = LockedDates.GetAll();
    return from p in v where p.EmployeeID == null || p.EmployeeID == employeeID select p;
```

Comment: No because the company might have non-working days that are the same as the employees.