# Get a List of Dates In a Date Range

Tags: c#, asp.net

Say I have a list of LockedDate.

A LockedDate has a DateTime and an IsYearly bool. If IsYearly is true then the year should not be considered because it could be any year. Time should never be considered.

Ex: X-Mas, Dec 25 is yearly.

Now I have a List of LockedDate.

There are no duplicates.

Now I need this function:

> This function will do:
>   If a LockedDate is NOT yearly and the day, month, and year are within the range from source, add to return list.
>
> If a LockedDate IS yearly, and its month / day fall in the range, then add a new date for each year in the range.
>
> Say I have Dec 25 with IsYearly as true. My range is Jan 22 2013 to Feb 23 2015 inclusive.  would need to add Dec 25 2013 as a new date and Dec 25 2014 as a new Date to the list.

```
List<Date> GetDateRange(List<LockedDate> source, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{


}
```

Thanks

```
Dec 25 Yearly -> Dec 25 2013, Dec 25 2014
Dec 2, 2011  NOT Yearly -> Nothing
March 25, 2013 => March 25 2013
```

Comment: "My range is Jan 22 2013 to Feb 23 2013 inclusive. I would need to add Dec 25 2013 as a new date and Dec 25 2014 as a new Date to the list." - Can you explain this.

Comment: You should show sample data and an expected output at a minimum. Also, there is no `Date` but `DateTime` in .NET, do you mean this?

Comment: Yes, I mean DateTime, hence why I said Time should not be considered

Comment: Sorry I mean Feb 22 2015

Comment: -1 your only problem is that you haven't written the code yet.

Answer (score 2):

This might give you at least an idea<strike>, it's not tested at all yet</strike>:

```
List<DateTime> GetDateRange(List<LockedDate> source, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    if (start > end)
        throw new ArgumentException("Start must be before end");

    var ts = end - start;
    var dates = Enumerable.Range(0, ts.Days)
        .Select(i => start.AddDays(i))
        .Where(d => source.Any(ld => ld.Date == d
            || (ld.IsYearly && ld.Date.Month == d.Month && ld.Date.Day == d.Day)));
    return dates.ToList();
}
```

**Update** Here's the demo with your sample data, it seems to work: http://ideone.com/3KFi97

Comment: I think it could be called a brute force solution :)

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I have not said that it's the most efficient approach, but it might be one of the most readable. He can optimize it when it's really too slow and he has confirmed that this is actually what he want. Also, the `List<LockedDate>` seems to be small.

Comment: I'm not saying that brute force is bad in every situation. Just saying that it can be done more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want without using Linq:

```
    List<DateTime> GetDateRange(List<LockedDate> source, DateTime start, DateTime end)
    {
        List<DateTime> result = new List<DateTime>();

        foreach (LockedDate lockedDate in source)
        {
            if (!lockedDate.IsYearly && (lockedDate.Date >= start && lockedDate.Date <= end))
            {
                result.Add(lockedDate.Date);
            }
            else if (lockedDate.IsYearly && (lockedDate.Date >= start && lockedDate.Date <= end))
            {
                DateTime date = new DateTime(start.Year, lockedDate.Date.Month, lockedDate.Date.Day);

                do
                {
                    result.Add(date);
                    date = date.AddYears(1);
                } while (date <= end);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Make sure to ask about parts you don't understand, so I can explain in detail, but I think it's pretty straightforward.

This code assumes your `LockedDate` class has a property `Date` for the `DateTime` object.

Comment: Not quite because this:  else if (lockedDate.IsYearly && (lockedDate.Date >= start && lockedDate.Date <= end)) takes the yearly's year into account when in fact it should be more like: for each day in the range as date, if the IsYearly's month and day match, add a new date with month, day, and year of current day you are iterating.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Class LockedDate like this:

```
public class LockedDate
{
       public DateTime Date { get; set; }
       public bool IsYearly { get; set; }
       ...
}
```

Than you could use this code to get your needed dates:

```
List<DateTime> GetDateRange(List<LockedDate> source, DateTime start, DateTime end)
{

       List<DateTime> dt = new List<DateTime>();
       foreach(LockedDate d in source)
       {
             if(!d.IsYearly)
             {
                  if(start<=d.Date && d.Date<=end)
                       dt.Add(d.Date);
             }
             else
             {
                  for(DateTime i = new DateTime(start.Year,d.Date.Month,d.Date.Day);i<=new DateTime(end.Year,d.Date.Month,d.Date.Day);i=i.AddYears(1))
                  {
                        dt.Add(i);
                  }
             }

      }
      return dt;
}
```

Comment: It won't work, because `i.AddYears(1)` returns new `DateTime` object, which is not saved anywhere. You have an infinite loop there!

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek You're right, updated my answer, it was a minor bug, I'm sure you are not such nitpicker since the code is generally OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
var notYearly = lockDates.Where(d => !d.IsYearly && (d.Date.Date >= start && d.Date.Date <= end)).Select(d => d.Date);

var years = ((end - start).Days / 365) + 2;
var startYear = start.Year;

var yearly = lockDates.Where(d => d.IsYearly)
                        .SelectMany(d => Enumerable.Range(startYear, years)
                                                    .Select(e => new DateTime(e, d.Date.Month, d.Date.Day))
                                                    .Where(i => i.Date >= start && i.Date <= end));

var allDates = notYearly.Union(yearly)
```

Should be more efficient than just iterating through all days between start and end and checking, if that date ok.